# How to find out duplicate inline css styles?

Tags: css, duplicates, newsletter

I've got a huge HTML newsletter file, in which I am supposed to remove duplicate CSS rules, however all of the rules are inline based.

I've been searching all over the internet, but everything ( eg css lint ) seems to be for external css files.

Do you know about anything I can use for my case?

EDIT: okay, since I've got already 2 dislikes, I would reword it to: How would You approach this problem?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be to introduce a type of templating system for emails so you would be able to write in external css or sass files and the final build step would output the inline styles (using something like the "MJML - The Responsive Email Framework" or "Zurbs Foundation for Emails").